# Using scanf to read up until dash in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read songs into string variables in C.
I use a dash ("-") to distinguish between the artist and the song.
This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *artist, *song;
    printf("Please copy all of the songs you wish to download below.\n");
    printf("When you have finished, please input a full stop.\n\n");
    scanf("%[^-] %s", artist, song);
    printf("%s %s\n", artist, song);
    return 0;
}
```

When I use this program, entering, for example, "artist - song", the output is as follows:

```
Please copy all of the songs you wish to download below.
When you have finished, please input a full stop.

artist - song
artist  (null)
```

I have tried using `scanf("%[^-] %[^\n]", artist, song);` and the result is the same.

How would I get everything after the dash to be read?

Comment: `%[^-]-%s` should be good to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`artist` and `song` are pointers. They do not point anywhere valid. You cannot use them before you make them point somewhere valid.

Try arrays instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char artist[100], song[100]; // arrays, not pointers
    printf("Please copy all of the songs you wish to download below.\n");
    printf("When you have finished, please input a full stop.\n\n");
    if (scanf("%99[^-]-%99s", artist, song) != 2) /* error */;
    printf("%s %s\n", artist, song);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to use pointers, allocate memory for them before input

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf(), scanf() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc(), free() */

int main(void) {
    char *artist, *song;
    artist = malloc(100);
    if (!artist) /* error */;
    song = malloc(100);
    if (!song) /* error */;
    printf("Please copy all of the songs you wish to download below.\n");
    printf("When you have finished, please input a full stop.\n\n");
    if (scanf("%99[^-]-%99s", artist, song) != 2) /* error */;
    printf("%s %s\n", artist, song);
    free(song);
    free(artist);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inclusion of `<stdlib.h>` or `<malloc.h>` is necessary in the second version in order to have a definition of `malloc`

Comment: Be aware that this will also read up any trailing spaces after the actual artist title, until the dash character `'-'`; as well as the preceding spaces before the actual song title. Getting rid of the preceding spaces would be as easy as changing the format-string into `"%99[^-]- %99s"` (mind the space, will match and consume at least zero white-space characters). Getting rid of the trailing spaces wouldn't be as easy.

Comment: The `scanf()` specifier `"%s"` (as well as many others) already discards leading whitespace. Post edited for `<stdlib.h>`. Thank you @ThoAppelsin

Comment: You're right, my bad. But hey, I just realized that this will only grab the first word of the song, then, which arguably is even worse. A scanset type-specifier like `"%99[^\n]"` instead of the simple `"%99s"` would be better for song assignment, in which case the space would have a use. In that case, the song would also suffer from trailing spaces, whatever...

Comment: yes ... this is all very basic. The best method **ALWAYS** is to use `fgets()` to get a full line, then parse that full line.